# Appfabric expiration event

Tags: events, caching, appfabric

What event can I use to subscribe to expiration events with AppFabric?

I put an object into the cache and a method of that object should be called when the cache expires it and the object is being removed.

It seems that AppFabric doesn't provide such event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct; AppFabric Cache does not provide an expiration event.  I could certainly make use of this feature should it be added in the future, but for now we'll have to get by without it (or without AppFabric).

Microsoft has had scant little to say about it other than [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/velocity/thread/48469c46-2ec8-4c64-b441-86e1fa1c846d) I found.

Other, similar, products do contain [expiration events](http://www.scaleoutsoftware.com/support/stateServer/soss_JNCdoc/com/scaleoutsoftware/soss/client/NamedCacheObjectExpirationListener.html) (e.g., ScaleOut Software's StateServer) but you would have to purchase the product.

-Seth